# selenium c# browser not launching

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm helping a coworker get selenium webdriver setup on a laptop. We're using Visual Studio 2013, NUnit 2.6.3 and Selenium dotnet 2.4.9. When running a simple "hello world" test the browser does not launch. The test does appear to run and pass however. We have tried chrome and firefox. The chrome driver is downloaded and in the path. There are no error messages, the browser simply does not launch. The test passes and the browser launches on my laptop fine.

```
public class HelloWorldTests
{
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void My_Test_Setup()
    {
        {
            // Navigate to Google
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Search_Test()
    {
        {
            // Test Search
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Hello World");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("sblsbb")).Click();                
        }
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void My_Test_TearDown()
    {
        driver.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both laptops have the same configuration? NUnit version, Selenium version etc? also check the browsers versions.

Comment: What are you using to run your tests??

Comment: Chrome is in the path, but the code is using the FF driver. Are you sure that is not the issue?